# Laravel: how to retrieve all instances of child models which extend from parent model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, database-normalization

We have records of different models but they extend from the same parent model.

I have a page where I would like to display a list of all records of that parent. How would one retrieve all records as the parent model?

example:

```
class LivingBeing extends Model{
    public function isAlive(){
         return $this->is_alive; //boolean
    }
}

class Human extends LivingBeing{
    use hasSpine; //eloquent handling for spine data
    $table = 'humans';
}

class Cat extends LivingBeing{
    use hasSpine; //eloquent handling for spine data
    $table = 'cats';
}

class Squid extends LivingBeing{
    use hasTentacles; //eloquent handling for tentacle data
    $table = 'squids';
}
```

I would like to retrieve a morphable eloquent collection of data like:

```
App\Models\LivingBeing //Human 1
App\Models\LivingBeing //Cat 1
App\Models\LivingBeing //Cat 2
App\Models\LivingBeing //Squid 1
```

is there a way to query all LivingBeings model similar to.. ?

```
LivingBeing::all()
```

I only used biological things as example. our system implements the same as documents instead. :)

Comment: I guess you can't do that. However you can have an array of classes extending the base class and then run database query for each of the class and concatenate the resulting collections into one and send it to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on how you stored the models in database.

### First Approach : Species as a field

if you have one table for **living_beings** and it has a column name **species**

you can access all with:

```
LivingBeing::all();
```

and in each model you have to implement the scope:

```
public static function boot()
     {
         parent::boot();
         static::addGlobalScope("specie", function ($query) {
             //specify type in child class
             //$query->where("specie_type", "cat");
             
             //specify in child if you have a species table
             //$query->where("specie_id", 2);
             
             //i think you can do it in parent once but i am not sure
             $query->where("specie", this::class.'');
         });
     }
```

### Second Approach : every Species has a table with living being table

each species has a field name living_being_id

access each species

```
Cat::all();
```

or by living being:

```
    LivingBeing::select("*")::join("cats","cats.living_being_id","living_beings.id")->get();
```

### Third Approach : (not recommended - not data normalized ) every species has a table itself.

to get all species, you have to union query:

```
Cat::all()->union(Dog::all());
```

## Conclusion

The Best is Approach #1

Comment: "normalized" is irrelevant to queries. And rearranging between designs for supertypes & subtypes is not normalization. What are you trying to say by "not data normalized" & why do you think that would lead to "not recommended"?

Comment: because species has share common features, we store them as 'column' in database. if we have  one table for each species we will end with having **redundant** column for every species which could be share with a `living_beings` table.

Comment: lets say *Cat* and *Dog* has some common properties need to save in data_base like *eye_color* , *weight* , *length* . if we **redefine** these properties in their table,i think it results in *not normalized Database Schema*

Comment: Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by projections of it that natural join back to it. What you call "redundant" is not what is called "redundancy" that normalization addresses & isn't "redundant" in any sense the word is normally used about DBs. (Which is that something is being needlessly recorded more than once.) These misconceptions are just what my 1st comment was talking about.